# Is it possible in django when user is login that time user active login browser name store in database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, django, python-3.x, django-admin

Django in we already store session details in django_session, and last_login in the auth_user table but I want to store when user login in browser that time browser name store in the database.

I already do: get browser name in frontend page from active browser with the use of javascript but actually, I want its store in the database.

I expect the output is store active browser name in the database.

This is my javascript code:

````
<html>
<body>
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
    let browserName = "";
    if(navigator.vendor.match(/google/i)) {
        browserName = 'Browser Name: Google Chrome';
    }
    else if(navigator.vendor.match(/apple/i)) {
        browserName = 'Browser Name: Apple Safari';
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.match(/firefox\//i)) {
        browserName = 'Browser Name: Mozila Firefox';
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.match(/edge\//i)) {
        browserName = 'Browser Name: Microsoft Edge';
    }
    else if(navigator.userAgent.match(/trident\//i)) {
        browserName = 'Browser Name: Internet Explorer';
    }
    else
    {
        browserName = navigator.userAgent + "\n" + navigator.vendor;
    }
</script>
    <h2><script type="text/javascript">document.write(browserName)</script></h2>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '')` and to parse this information in an easy way, check out https://pypi.org/project/user-agents/.

Example from the documentation (`ua_string` would be the result of the request statement):

```
from user_agents import parse

# iPhone's user agent string
ua_string = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3'
user_agent = parse(ua_string)

# Accessing user agent's browser attributes
user_agent.browser  # returns Browser(family=u'Mobile Safari', version=(5, 1), version_string='5.1')
user_agent.browser.family  # returns 'Mobile Safari'
user_agent.browser.version  # returns (5, 1)
user_agent.browser.version_string   # returns '5.1'

# Accessing user agent's operating system properties
user_agent.os  # returns OperatingSystem(family=u'iOS', version=(5, 1), version_string='5.1')
user_agent.os.family  # returns 'iOS'
user_agent.os.version  # returns (5, 1)
user_agent.os.version_string  # returns '5.1'

# Accessing user agent's device properties
user_agent.device  # returns Device(family=u'iPhone', brand=u'Apple', model=u'iPhone')
user_agent.device.family  # returns 'iPhone'
user_agent.device.brand # returns 'Apple'
user_agent.device.model # returns 'iPhone'

# Viewing a pretty string version
str(user_agent) # returns "iPhone / iOS 5.1 / Mobile Safari 5.1"
```

Comment: i can't found user agent getting  '__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slotnames__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_asdict', '_fields', '_fields_defaults', '_make', '_replace', 'count' 'family''index','version' 'version_string'

Comment: Have you installed it properly like mentioned on the documentation page?

Answer (score 0):

You can get user agent from `request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '')`. You have to write middleware to store this data

or

you can also use this package for storing user agent with Geo IP https://django-user-sessions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/